# <?= short tags not working

Tags: php, tags

I'm running on windows 7 with php 5.3.1. some of the examples I see on the internet uses short tags instead of echo.

so why doesn't this work

```
<td><?=$row['name'];?></td>
```

but this works?

```
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
```

Comment: I guess I haven't search long enough.. also didn't see the notification of "This question may already have an answer here:" on top.. sorry. I can't delete this question anymore for there are answers posted already.

Comment: Accept one of the best answer then @dapidmini. I also to mention that you have an option to do something like `<? echo $row['name']; ?>` if short tag is enabled :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in you `php.ini`

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Then restart your server

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.4 the shorthand for [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) that you are showing is enabled by default. Prior to that it must be enabled in the configuration via the [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive.

It is changable `PHP_INI_PERDIR` meaning that is can be set in the php.ini, server config or in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Short tag or `short_open_tag` for some server is not enabled by default, and it is encourage to use the actual regular tag `<?php` because of the reason that if you want to do some migration from one server to another and if the other doesn't support it will break everything.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `short_open_tag` is disabled.

Open your `php.ini` file and set `short_open_tag` to `1`. Save the file and restart your web server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable short tags in your `php.ini` and restart your server as said by User016.

```
short_open_tag=On
```

`It's been recommended not to use the short tag "short cut" and instead to use the full <?php and ?> tag combination. With the wide spread use of XML and use of these tags by other languages, the server can become easily confused and end up parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. Also short tags may not be supported on the target server`